# How can I create an if/elseif/else statement based on an object literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, object-literal

I would like to have an if/else if/else statement based on an object literal. The object literal will be user generated and so I will not know how long it will be, though I will know the key/value pairs naming scheme.

For example, I have some code that gets the viewport width and a function to update img src attribute below

```
vpwidth =  window.innerWidth;

function modifyImgSrc (srcModifier) {
    src = src.replace(".jpg", srcModifier + ".jpg");
    src = src.replace(".png", srcModifier + ".png");
    src = src.replace(".gif", srcModifier + ".gif");
};
```

Then I have my object literal

```
var brkpnts = [
   {width: 320, srcmodifier: '-s'},
   {width: 768, srcmodifier: '-m'},
   {width: 1024, srcmodifier: '-l'},
];
```

And I want to generate an if statement based of the object literal

```
if ( vpwidth <= brkpnts[0].width ) {
    modifyImgSrc(brkpnts[0].srcmodifier);
}
else if ( vpwidth <= brkpnts[1].width ) {
    modifyImgSrc(brkpnts[1].srcmodifier);
}
else {
    modifyImgSrc(breakpoints[2].srcmodifier);
}
```

Though since the object literal can be modified by the user, how can I generate an if/else if/else statement to match what the user adds to the object literal. For example, the may have more than 3 key/value pairs.

```
var breakpoints = [
    {width: 320, srcmodifier: '-xs'},
    {width: 534, srcmodifier: '-s'},
    {width: 768, srcmodifier: '-m'},
    {width: 1024, srcmodifier: '-l'},
    {width: 1440, srcmodifier: '-xl'}
];
```

In that case, I would want an if statement that looked like this.

```
if ( vpwidth <= brkpnts[0].width ) {
    modifyImgSrc(brkpnts[0].srcmodifier);
}
else if ( vpwidth <= brkpnts[1].width ) {
    modifyImgSrc(brkpnts[1].srcmodifier);
}
else if ( vpwidth <= brkpnts[2].width ) {
    modifyImgSrc(brkpnts[1].srcmodifier);
}
else if ( vpwidth <= brkpnts[3].width ) {
    modifyImgSrc(brkpnts[1].srcmodifier);
}
else {
    modifyImgSrc(breakpoints[4].srcmodifier);
}
```

Is this possible? 
If so, how, and is this the best way to achieve this?

Comment: why not use proper *CSS* and ***Media Queries*** - given the images are referenced in the CSS the appropriate image will be fetched for the screen size. This solution will require you to change from using `<img/>` to some block level element and `background-image`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Xander. Using media-queries and background images is a valid solution, though I'm working on a solution for content images where it would be best to leave them as img elements rather than background images. I believe this easier for sites like Facebook/Pinterest to grab images from img elements rather than background images from divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array:

```
var modified = false;
for(var i = 0, len = brkpnts.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(vpwidth <= brkpnts[i].width) {
        modifyImgSrc(brkpnts[i].srcmodifier);
        modified = true;
        break;
    }
}

// Use the biggest one if vpwidth larger than all
if(!modified) {
    modifyImgSrc(brkpnts[brkpnts.length - 1].srcmodifier);
}
```

**Edit:** Though, Xander is correct in his comment, you should probably use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
vpwidth =  window.innerWidth;  

function modifyImgSrc (srcModifier) {     
  src = src.replace(".jpg", srcModifier + ".jpg");     
  src = src.replace(".png", srcModifier + ".png");     
  src = src.replace(".gif", srcModifier + ".gif"); 
}; 

var breakpoints = [     
  {width: 320, srcmodifier: '-xs'},      
  {width: 534, srcmodifier: '-s'},     
  {width: 768, srcmodifier: '-m'},     
  {width: 1024, srcmodifier: '-l'},      
  {width: 1440, srcmodifier: '-xl'} 
];

for(var i=0; i<breakpoints.length;i++)
{
  if(breakpoints[i].width == vpwidth)
  {
     modifyImgSrc(breakpoints[i].srcmodifier);
     break;
  }
}
```